# Workflow Config Manager - Security Token error

Tags: sharepoint-designer

[image]can any one help me on this i am getting below error

Comment: I would start with writing a proper Subject header. What would happen if all StackOverflow posts started with Subjects like you now wrote?

Comment: Whenever I am installing the work flow manager&Service bus through Webplatform Installer I go struck at this position please help me how to solve it

Comment: How many servers are you installing your WFM?